# How do I modify the output of iframes generated by Media oEmbed module?

Tags: 7, media

I'm trying to add a title attribute to all iframes outputted by the D7 media_oembed module with Youtube videos, but can't find the write entry point for it. There aren't any templates with the raw structure to override.

Can someone point me to the right place please?

Comment: Can you specify where are the iframes you're referring to? The media module, by itself, stores/display media files local to the Drupal installation.

Comment: I've updated the op.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML is being generated by the YouTube oEmbed API.

If you inspect the **themes/media-oembed.tpl.php** template & the theme preprocess include **themes/media_oembed.theme.inc**, you can see that  `media_oembed_get_data()` looks up the plugin which pulls the data from the API. In the returned data, the `html` element is used to fill the `$content` variable in the template.

The module provides a few different means to hook into retrieval/process/display of the data:

1. `hook_media_oembed_request_alter($parameters, $plugin, $url)` can be evoked to alter data before plugin retrieval.
2. `hook_media_oembed_response_alter($embed)` can be evoked to alter data after plugin retrieval.
3. `hook_preprocess_media_oembed(&$variables)` can be evoked before processing the template for display.

Whatever means you use, it looks like you'll need to manipulate the HTML string directly to add the `title` element to your output.